# How to properly include GoogleAdMobAds?

Tags: iphone, adsense

I have iOS 7 on my iphone, OSX 10.8.5 on mac and Xcode 5. When I run application from xcode on device or simulator everything is ok but when I try to "Archive" I get this error with google ads:
[image]

and this frameworks I have included:

[image]

What I have done wrong?

Comment: check wether your files related to AdMob are within your application bundle it seems like it's referenced from some other place from your error.

Comment: you have "Under Other Linker Flags, add -ObjC to both Debug and Release" ? Also, try to change your Architecture from "default arm64, armv7,etc" to "default armv7s, etc"

Comment: @thebenjiman my solution is for the actual binary architecture released. What is your solution, to wait? Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you just have to wait for Google Admob team to deliver a binary supporting 64bits architecture.. last update on their blog was from last month for iOS; this month for Windows phones. Hope we'll not have to wait to much to finally support 64bit in our apps.

Comment: There isn't any arm64 support yet, you're right.

Remove arm64 from your Build Settings and build the Active Architectures only when you Archive for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

go target->build settings->architectures

change to standard  , the one not using the arm64   which admob not support , then clean and archive again